# Getting this error `This action is not allowed as it is outside the current transaction` in jmeter script for Pega application

Tags: jmeter, pega

I am doing `performance testing` for `Pega application`. Getting the below error when I try to replay the jmeter script. Below is the error snapshot. Could someone help me here

```
Below is the error

This action is not allowed as it is outside the current transaction.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay recorded test script against more or less complex web application without performing [correlation of the dynamic parameters](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter).

Also looking into [this thread](https://collaborate.pega.com/question/performance-testing#comment-374451):

> Was I while ago I did it but if I remember correct I had to use netscape cookie policy in the http cookie manager when upgrading to Jmeter 3.x. Also hade to use the JVM http implementation (HTTP request defaults -> Advanced -> Implementation: Java) instead of the standard Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 4.x.

> Also you probably need to extract the accessgroup when posting login, and in the flows you also need the pzTransactionId to keep state between pages.